# Flash + Box2d network problems, how to copy movement over network?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, box2d, multiplayer

Im trying to create a game similar to haxball.

Here is the sample

http://elearn72.net63.net/hax.html

Open it in two browsers and start moving with the arrows.

You will see the ball physics are ok, but I cant copy the physics of the small ball.

What do you recommend?

Regards,
Mirza

Answer (score 0):

Heyo Mirza,

Well i don't know what version of Box2DAS3 so i will write for 2.1a since it is the latest.

Looking at the link application you posted I'm guessing the following would be implemented.

- Zero Gravity (b2Vec2(0.0, 0.0))
- linearDamping & angularDamping (b2BodyDef)

So for the Gravity

```
public var World:b2World;
public var Gravity:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(0.0, 0.0);
public var AllowSleep:Boolean = true;

public function Example(){

World = new b2World(Gravity, AllowSleep);

}
```

For damping you would create a new body and on the body's definition use

```
//0.3 can changed be any Number
bodyDef.linearDamping = 0.3;
bodyDef.angularDamping = 0.3;
```

In Top-Down View linear,angular Damping would be used for Density, as in a Side-Scroller Density handles itself.

Hope this help's! -Zero